# Use algebra to decide the rectangle's area

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: Decide the area of the blue rectangle.]

I understand that with the usage of variables, I can use algebra to come up with the right area for the blue rectangle. So I let all the different sides be different variables.

[image]

Now I know that I need to find out what $cy$ is in order to come up with the right area. But I'm lost. I do know that $c * x = x * z + 39$ and that $y * z = x * z + 18$ but I don't know how I could use that information, if at all. I would be very happy if someone could help and explain this!

(The answer should be $180m^2$ according to my math book).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking too complicatedly.
You know that $z=z$, therefore the ratio between $y$ and $x$ is 
$$\frac{135}{117} = \frac{15}{13}$$

Then
$$cy = \frac{15}{13}, cx = \frac{15}{13}\cdot156=180$$

Answer (score 1):

Since we have
$$cx=156$$
$$zx=117$$
$$yz=135$$
we have
$$cy=\frac{156}{x}\cdot y=\frac{156}{x}\cdot\frac{135}{z}=\frac{156\cdot 135}{xz}=\frac{156\cdot 135}{117}.$$